# How to initialize onclick method before ModalPopupExtender take place?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

because I manually want to show the modal popup (this might be due to the fact that the controls inside the popup have to initialized according to the pressed button or row). Can anyone help me? The button NEVER goes to this EditBtn_Click method, it just aways show my panel.

Code:

```
      protected void EditBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);

        string uid = (string)ManageStaffGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;

        //bind panel


        AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender mpe = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)row.FindControl("EditBtn_ModalPopupExtender");
        mpe.Show(); //show the modal popup extender

    }
```

Design:

(from grid)

```
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="EditBtn" runat="server" onclick="EditBtn_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="EditBtn_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" CancelControlID="CancelBtn" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="UpdatePanel" TargetControlID="EditBtn">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 </ItemTemplate>

<asp:Panel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" Style="display: none" BackColor="White" GroupingText="Update User">
<div>
<table><tr>
<td style="width:12px"></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="lblLegend" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr></table>
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:12px"></td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStaffName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:12px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblUserId" runat="server" Text="User ID"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStaffUid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top" style="width: 70px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSection" runat="server" Text="Section"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:ListBox ID="listSection" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
        CssClass="standardManage" onMouseDown="GetCurrentListValues(this);" 
        onchange="FillListValues(this);">
    </asp:ListBox>
    </td>
<td valign="top">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredValidatorSection" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="listSection" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" 
        EnableTheming="True" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Label ID="lblValidatorSection" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFunction" runat="server" Text="Function"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFunction" runat="server" CssClass="standardManage">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblStaffGender" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text="Role"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" CssClass="standardManage">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 76px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 70px">
    &nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="UpdateBtn" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click"/>&nbsp;
     <asp:Button ID="CancelBtn" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </td>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></asp:Panel>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a very helpful link that eventually solves my problems! Please check it out!
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-show-modalpopup-to-edit-gridview.html